# Date in HTML and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date, visual-studio-2015

I have a ASP.net project in visual studio for a website.
There are some products stored in the server.Angular gets the products from the server and shows them on website.
There is product class:

```
 public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Category category { get; set; }
}
```

Then in Angular:

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

   //get data from server
    $http.post("WebService.asmx/GetProducts")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.products = angular.copy(response.data);});  
}
```

And In HTML There are some inputs,where show the information of product:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="current.name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name" required>
 <input type="text" ng-model="current.description" class="form-control" id="descr" placeholder="description" required>
 <input  ng-model="current.price" type="number" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="price" required>
 <input type="date" ng-model="current.date"  class="form-control" id="date" required>
 <input type="text" ng-model="current.category.name" class="form-control" id="cat" placeholder="category" required>
```

OK. The Problem is that I dont know how to show the income date of product.
My Questions are:

**1)What type should date be in Product class?**

**2)There is date type input for the date of product in HTML.How can I make the date of product to be shown as Date in the Input?**

**3) And after changing the input,how to change the date attribute of product?**

Comment: 1) Use Date datatype in the .NET class. 2) What's the problem, is it not showing it correctly now? What happens if you change the .NET to Date type? 3) I guess once you post the data back to the server if will update the value...not sure what else you mean here

Comment: Best to show what you've tried.